# JButton not showing up in scroll pane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I'm trying to setup a basic GUI Library that will import a list of books and display each book as a `JButton` within a scroll pane. But, before getting there I'm just trying to orient the panels first and adding a test button to make sure the basics are working before moving on to the details.

I've tried moving code around to add panels in different orders to see if that was an issue but keep getting the same result. I'm completely new to this, so my understanding of it is very limited.

```
public class LibraryPanel extends JPanel{

    private Library library;
    private JPanel bookButtons, importBooks;
    JScrollPane bookList;
    JTextField importField;
    JButton load;

    public LibraryPanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,500));
        Library library = new Library();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Library"));

        // Import Books Panel
        importBooks = new JPanel();
        importBooks.setLayout(new    BoxLayout(importBooks,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        importBooks.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Import Books"));
        importField = new JTextField(15);
        importBooks.add(importField);
        load = new JButton("Load");
        importBooks.add(load);
        this.add(importBooks,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        load.addActionListener(new loadButtonListener());
        // Book List buttons
        JPanel bookButtons = new JPanel();
        bookButtons.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bookButtons,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JButton testButton = new JButton("TEST Button");
        bookButtons.add(testButton);

        //for(int i = 0; i<library.getBooks().size(); i++) {
        //  BookButton button = new BookButton(library.getBook(i));
            //button.addActionListener(new BookButtonListener());
        //  bookButtons.add(button);
        //}

        // Scroll Pane
                bookList = new JScrollPane();
                bookList.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Book List"));
                bookList.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
                bookList.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
                this.add(bookList,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                bookList.add(bookButtons);
    }
    private class loadButtonListener implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String filename = new String(importField.getText());
            library.loadLibraryFromCSV(filename);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm having an issue with the test button not showing up at all within the scroll pane. The panels are there but not the test button.

Comment: You can't "add" components to a `JScrollPane`, you need to use the scroll pane's `viewPort` view

Comment: 1) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "add" components to a `JScrollPane`, this isn't how they work.  A `JScrollPane` uses a `JViewport` as it's primary component, which is then used to determine when the scrollbars should be used.

See [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

[image: scrollpane]

Instead of...

```
bookList = new JScrollPane();
//...
bookList.add(bookButtons);
```

simply do...

```
bookList = new JScrollPane(bookButtons);
//...
//bookList.add(bookButtons);
```